# How can I Unit Test PlayMode behaviours with a Scriptable Object Channel based setup for my Unity game?

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine, channel, scriptable-object

I'm writing a card game in Unity and have a setup where all my MonoBehaviour objects communicate through SO channels. For example,

GraphicsEngine <= GameManager <=> AI

I would like to write some PlayMode unit tests that, for example, set all of the players to AI and run through a deal.

I want to do something like the following:

```
    public class MyTest 
    { 
        [UnityTest] 
        public IEnumerator RunThroughWithAllPlayersAI() 
        { 
            GameManager gameManager = "Some kind of mock GameManager but with Channels correctly loaded"; 
            gameManager.NSAreAI = true; 
            gameManager.waitAfterTrick = false; 
            gameManager.fixRandomSeed = false; 
            gameManager.DealCards(); 
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); 
            Assert.True(true); 
        } 
}
```

I'm not sure I can do this with interfaces because I don't think the SO Channels will be correctly loaded.

Comment: I don't think you're using the word channel correctly here, channel is usually a multithreading concept by my understanding. Can you please clarify what you mean by it?

Comment: The very first line of the code seems.. odd.. you are initializing the object gameManager as a string but then referencing parameters as bool types and even invoke a method called DealCards().  Part 2, you cannot instantiate interfaces but must define a transient that inherits the interface.

Comment: By Channel I mean a scriptable object that is used to send and receive messages between GameObjects. Here is an example used in a Unity Demo Project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLDgtRNK2VE. Also the first line of code is just intended to be pseudo code.